# How to set fo:external-graphic under text?

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm making "XML to PDF" transformation using XSL-FO and when I try to put an image with external-graphic in absolute coordinates and text in the same way, the picture is ALWAYS above the text even if I change z-index attribute.

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/fofixedposn.html#d12186e70) can help you. I don't know why they choose option 2, because it feels a little dirty to me. I'd go with option 1, unless the image is the background of the entire page. If that's the case choose option 3.